# jqgrid select tag options ordering

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid in my rails project with jqgrid_rails gem,
I added select tag option as `{'true' => 'Active', 'false' => 'Inactive'}` in the jqgrid like this,

```
@grid = JqGridRails::JqGrid.new('users_table', 
  :url => "#", 
  :height => '100%',
  :width => 900,
  :caption => 'User Listing'
)
@grid.add_column('Active', 'active', {
  :stype => 'select', 
  :editoptions => {'value' => {'true' => 'Active', 'false' => 'Inactive'}}
})
```

in view it genetates html tag like this,

```
<select style="width: 100%;" name="active" id="gs_active">
  <option value="false">Inactive</option>
  <option value="true">Active</option>
</select>
```

But i am looking to generate html tag with 'Active' as the first option like this,

```
<select style="width: 100%;" name="active" id="gs_active">
  <option value="true">Active</option></select>
  <option value="false">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way order the select tag options? if not it will be fine to set the default selected value to be 'Active'

Answer (score 1):

```
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#gs_active").val('true');
  });
```

after page load, set the select tag selected value to 'true' by jquery